# SSL certificate verify failed while configuring mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm

I am trying to add a json file to mongo db database as a collection. I have installed pymongo module from pycharm terminal. I can connect using mongoDB compass as well. But is is giving this error while trying to connect through code.

```
"pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-01.m49ca.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate...."
```

My code is here:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('first part of conn string' + urllib.parse.quote('password') + 'second part of conn string')"
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Do you know which root CA issued the certificate to the server?

Comment: @BellyBuster i am using windows 10